# Redirect specific traffic through a VPN interface

Tags: iptables, vpn, redirect, interface, iproute2

I,

I would like to redirect specific ports through a specific interface.

Until now what I accomplished it was

```
 cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables | grep "200 force.route" > /dev/null
 if [ $? != 0 ]; then
   echo "200       force.route" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
 fi

 ip rule del from all fwmark 200 table force.route
 ip rule add from all fwmark 200 table force.route
 ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 via 92.240.245.1 dev tun_02 table force.route
 ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 92.240.245.1 dev tun_02 table force.route
 ip route flush cache
 iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o br0 -p icmp -j MARK --set-mark 200
```

But....

when I ping the packages go through the specific device see with

```
 tcpdump -i tun_02
```

then, expecting response but I don't have a response to echo-request.

How can I accomplish that ?

Until now is what I accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulution :
Need to add the following two rules:
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 92.240.245.1 dev tun_02 table force.route

AND THE MISSING ONE
ip route add default via 92.240.245.1 dev tun_02 table force.route